# Evitar que se pierdan los datos de un formulario

Tags: c#, razor

Al seleccionar una opción del select se envía automaticamente los datos seleccionados al controlador, lo envio con esto `onchange="this.form.submit()"`

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">Provincia de la Sucursal:</label>
       <select onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control" name="codigoProvincia">
          <option selected>Selecciona una Provincia:</option>
              @foreach (var item in Model.Provincias)
               {
                  <option value="@item.codigo">@item.ubicacion</option>
               }
       </select>
</div>
```

Yo selecciono una provincia de ese select, envía el código al controlador, busca en un `json` los corregimiento que corresponden a esa provincia y me los devuelve seguido de eso otro `select` debe de llenarse con los distritos encontrado, lo que sucede es que cada que selecciono una opción de cada `select` se me refresca la página y se pierden los datos que ya escribí en cualquier otro campo y quiero evitar eso.

***CODIGO***

```
public IActionResult ViewInfoEmisor(string codigoProvincia, string codigoDistrito)
        {
            //Debido a que usare mas de 1 modelo en la vista creo un modelo que contendrá esos otros modelos como los de Provincia, Distritos...
            Selects modelo = new();

            //Leo el texto de los archivos:
                StreamReader readerProvincias = new("./json/CatalogoProvincias.json");
                StreamReader readerDistritos = new("./json/CatalogoDistritos.json");
                StreamReader readerCorregimientos = new("./json/CatalogoCorregimientos.json");

            //Leo todos los caracteres desde la posicion actual hasta el final de la secuencia
                string jsonStringD = readerDistritos.ReadToEnd();
                string jsonStringPr = readerProvincias.ReadToEnd();
                string jsonStringCr = readerCorregimientos.ReadToEnd();

            //Deserializo
                List<Provincias> provincias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Provincias>>(jsonStringPr);
                List<Distritos> distritos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Distritos>>(jsonStringD);
                List<Corregimientos> corregimientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Corregimientos>>(jsonStringCr);

            //Filtra los distritos encontrados con el codigo de la provincia seleccionada en el select de provincia
                List<Distritos> distritosSeleccionados = distritos.Where(x => x.codigo.Split("-")[0] == codigoProvincia).ToList();

            //Filtra los corregimientos encontrados con el codigo del distrito seleccionado en el select de distritos
                List<Corregimientos> corregimientosSeleccionados = corregimientos.Where(x => x.codigo.StartsWith(codigoDistrito)).ToList();
 
                modelo.Provincias = provincias;
                modelo.Distritos = distritosSeleccionados;
                modelo.Corregimientos = corregimientosSeleccionados;

            return View(modelo);
        }
```

Una vez seleccionada una provincia los distritos encontrados se mandan a la vista para llenar un select (Funciona) pero se recarga la página y se pierden los demás datos escritos.

Comment: Evitar que se refresque o evitar que se pierdan los datos?

Comment: Si tienes razon, que se pierden los datos, ya lo corrigo

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que la pagina se puede refrescar sin perder los datos, esto lo haces reenviando los datos. La otra solución es con ajax, ahí no se refresca la página ni se pierden los datos. La primera forma es más fácil que la segunda

Comment: Y como hago para reenviar los datos con la primera forma?, estoy buscando pero por ahora no encuentro como.

Comment: En la función que recibe los datos (en el controlador), pones que te reciba los datos del form, luego se los vuelves a pasar a la vista en el `return View(datos,"nombrevista")`

Comment: Podrías hacer un ejemplo de cómo sería utilizando `Ajax`?

Comment: El problema es el submit: submit(). No se porque cada vez que se selecciona algo se envía al controlador (Eso es molestar demasiado al servidor). Y si del todo es necesario enviar esto al servidor a cada rato entonces tiene que poner el select fuera del formulario y llamar un metodo en el onchange que  envie la data  utilzando fetch o mediante axios o bien a la vieja escuela con ajax

Comment: Pon el código del controlador

Comment: Ahí añadí el código del controlador